# Load Javascript+Html content in UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am trying load javascript + html content returning from the server in a uiwebview. Please find my code its not loading,

```html
<span class="wc5element"onclick="tvrTrackClick('chat')"><span class="wc5element"> </span><span class="wc5element"></span><divstyle="display: none;" id="WCcopyright"><a href="http://www.livecom.net">livecom.net chat</a></div><script charset="ISO-8859-1" type="text/javascript" src="//wheur.livecom.net/....="></script>
```

NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",decodevalue];
   [self.webView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.livecom.net/en/";

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[YourWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks this way it will work , i don't want to load  this url http://www.livecom.net/en/. Instead i want to load the html+javascript content as mentioned above which is a different page. I want to trigger the onclick functionality (onclick="tvrTrackClick('chat'))actually "<span class="wc5element"onclick="tvrTrackClick('chat')">"